# Powershell : File Copy : If File name contains special characters then not able to copy

Tags: powershell, filecopy

Windows 10 64 BIT

Scenario: copy files in a directory and subdirectory to the destination directory.
File Type: Only pdf
Issue: When the file name has special characters not able to copy

***Tried below code not working***

```
#Get all files and not the directories
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:/source" -Recurse -filter "*.pdf" | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}

#Copy items from sources to new destination
foreach ($file in $files)
{
if ($file.Name -match '[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
{
$file.FullName
*$file.FullName | Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace '_*(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\))_*' -replace '_+', ' '} $NewName
*Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace '_*(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\))_*' -replace '_+', ' '} 
*$NewName = rename-item $file.FullName.Replace('_*(\[*?\]|\(*?\))_*', '')
Rename-Item -Path $file.fullName -NewName {$_ -replace '_*(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\))_*' -replace '_+', ' '}
}
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "c:/desination\"
}
```

Comment: the `-LiteralPath` parameter is designed for just exactly that use. [*grin*]

Comment: As a general tip (@Lee_Dailey's hint may be all you need): "not working" is typically not specific enough to diagnose a problem; please show the specific error you're getting in your questions.

Comment: This is the Error                                                                                                    
 Copy-Item : The operation completed successfully.
At line:2 char:3
+ %{Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "c:\...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: @Avi, please add additional information _directly to the question_ - don't use comments. Also, please add a sample input path that produces the symptom.